# Animating a value of a tag attribute

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, web-animations-api

Is there a way to animate a value of [`dy` attribute of SVG's `tspan`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html#TSpanElementDYAttribute) using JavaScript, ideally using [Web Animations API](https://www.w3.org/TR/web-animations-1/)?

The value of `dy` is known to be animatable using `<animate />` element (as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34871733/80851)):

```html
<svg>
  <text x="30" y="30">FairBridge
    <animate attributeName="dy" from="0 0 0" to="0 -20 20" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </text>
</svg>
```

I am wondering if it's possible to convert that animation to JavaScript.

For context, I've been using [`KeyframeEffect`](https://www.w3.org/TR/web-animations-1/#creating-a-new-keyframeeffect-object) for all my previous animations, and would prefer to use it to animate the attribute value too in order to keep the animations code consistent.

In case there's absolutely no way to use `KeyframeEffect`, how would one go about animating a generic value of a tag attribute?

Comment: call setAttribute repeatedly via setInterval SMIL is much easier though.

Comment: @RobertLongson I am hearing `setInternal` is not particularly convenient to use in animations, as the interval set may not be respected strictly 

Comment: As I said, use SMIL.

Comment: WAAPI is, as far as I was able to ascertain, [not able](https://browser-unplugged.net/blog/waapi.en.html) to handle SMIL attribute animations.

Comment: @ccprog very nice, thanks for pointer! Out of curiosity, after a bit digging I've also found [this](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=596377&q=animate%20attribute%20SMIL&can=2) (Chromium), while failing to find a ticket with relevant title in Webkit/Firefox bug trackers.

Comment: Quote: "This was all in the interest of deprecating SMIL in favour of CSS and Web Animations. If that's no longer a priority then neither is this I suspect." Deprecating SMIL was an idea that Chrome devs had to [retract on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64514150#67471118) very soon after the anouncement.

Comment: It took some time to remember, but there is an older [article on CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-animate-text-with-svg-and-css/) that tried its hand at animating letters. There are several different approaches in the comments. Those that use CSS would be translatable to WAAPI.

Comment: @ccprog thanks a lot for links with further context on this!

Answer (score 0):

Only the [presentation attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/styling.html#PresentationAttributes) can be animated using [Web Animations API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API), because they are also CSS properties, XML attributes cannot.

In this example I can animate `fill` and `rotate`, but not `x` and `dy`. When I give the `x` property the wrong value (like `'100'` or `100`) I get an error in the FireFox console -- strange when the right value has no effect. `dy` is just ignored.

```js
var text1 = document.getElementById('text1');

var textKeyframes = new KeyframeEffect(
  text1, [{
      fill: 'red',
      rotate: '0deg',
      x: '0px',
      dy: '0px'
    },
    {
      fill: 'green',
      rotate: '90deg',
      x: '100px',
      dy: '100px'
    }
  ], {
    duration: 2000,
    fill: 'forwards'
  }
);

var textAnimation = new Animation(textKeyframes, document.timeline);

textAnimation.play();
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 800 200">
  <g transform="translate(100 100)">
    <text id="text1" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle"
      font-size="30">FairBridge </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Presentation attributes can be animated, because they are also CSS properties, XML attributes cannot. See the [authoritative list](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/styling.html#PresentationAttributes).

Comment: Thanks @ccprog. I will add that to my answer